# How to set path correctly from RBENV shims on Mac M1 with zsh

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I'm having trouble setting up the rbenv paths

I follow the instructions as specified here: [rbenv installation page](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#how-rbenv-hooks-into-your-shell)

I run the command on a zsh terminal:

```
rbenv init
```

The terminal gives me the instruction to run

```
eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"
```

I then close the restart the terminal and check to see if all is configured correctly by running:

`curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/main/bin/rbenv-doctor | bash`

and I get the following failure:

```
Checking for rbenv shims in PATH: not found
```

If I try open the fils .zshrc I find only the following path written to it

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/bin:$PATH"
```

but no shims. Can I add the shims manually?  I don't know what it should look like?  Or is there any reason the command `eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"` is not working properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working:  I need to run `echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc`